# fatal eror (Notepad++)

Tags: php, mysql, xampp, fatal-error

> Notice: Undefined variable: con in C:\xampp\htdocs\projekt\ps.php on line 34
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\projekt\ps.php on line 34

This opened in my browser, I looked for other replies on this question but I couldn't find an answer.

Problem is here in index.php

```
<?php
$res -$con->query("SELECT * FROM studenti");
while ($row=$res->fetch_array()){
?>
```

This is base:

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root','');
if(!$con)
{
    echo 'Not connected';
}
if(!mysqli_select_db($con,'studenti'))
{
    echo 'database not selected';
}
?>
```

Comment: What is that meant to be? `$res -$con->query(...)`?

Comment: And why is a file that contains php code named `index.html`? That won't work _unless_ you made some pretty strange modifications to your http server...

Comment: This is really not a good question. Please provide a full code example, you are missing half of the code.

Comment: sorry the file is index.php here is the code

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<?php
$res = $con->query("SELECT * FROM studenti");
while ($row=$res->fetch_array()){
?>
```

I changed `$res-$con` to `$res = $con`.

I think that was what you were aiming for?